# NGINX reverse proxy doesnt redirects me to my website

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have reverse proxy on `nginx`,
[my reverse proxy config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7ysW.png)
And when i try it, it redirects me on my phpmyadmin webpage, but it should redirects me to 89.31.45.132:25568.

And when I enter just IP it redirects me to phpmyadmin to.
Here is my config of phpmyadmin https://pteropaste.com/xt6z7y34byzt/

I tried to change proxy_pass.